# uploading files from Camera - error finding uri on android

Tags: android

I have a problem concerning sending image from camera. When I press Image button the function "openImageIntent()" is applied. Everything works until getPath(uri) is called. This throws an error as uri is taken as a null object. It is weird as this code was working before and now it crashes. I attach both openImageIntent function, onResult where it crashes and the error.

I will be grateful for any help. Thank you in advance.

PS 
Attaching files from gallery works.

```
 private void openImageIntent() {
// Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        Log.e("Start","yoyoyo");
        final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Eventime" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        final String fname = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
        Log.e("CheckOutput", outputFileUri.toString());

        // Camera.
        final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
            final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            Log.e("CheckOutput", outputFileUri.toString());
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            cameraIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // Filesystem.
        final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        // Chooser of filesystem options.
        final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

        // Add the camera options.
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[cameraIntents.size()]));

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (check) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    final boolean isCamera;
                    if (data == null) {
                        isCamera = true;
                    } else {
                        final String action = data.getAction();
                        if (action == null) {
                            isCamera = false;
                        } else {
                            isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        }
                    }

                    Uri uri;
                    if (isCamera) {
                        //selectedImageUri
                        uri = outputFileUri;

                    } else {
                        //uri = data.getData();
                        //selectedImageUri
                        uri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                    }

                    try {
                        path = getPath(uri);
//                beginUpload(path);
                    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(this,
                                "Unable to get the file from the given URI.  See error log for details",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("Upload Imagine", "Unable to upload file from the given uri", e);
                    }

                }
            }
            if (requestCode == 10) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    String name = null;
                    if (data.hasExtra("name")) {
                        name = data.getStringExtra("name");
                    }
                    exit(name);
                }
            }
            check = false;
        }
    }
```

Error log

FATAL EXCEPTION: main    Process: com.amazon.mysampleapp, PID: 12899

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.amazon.mysampleapp/com.mysampleapp.RegisterUser}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.amazon.mysampleapp/com.mysampleapp.RegisterUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.net.Uri.getPathSegments()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3392)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2761)
                                                                            at 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.amazon.mysampleapp/com.mysampleapp.RegisterUser}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.net.Uri.getPathSegments()' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List android.net.Uri.getPathSegments()' on a null object reference
                                                                            at android.provider.DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(DocumentsContract.java:698)
                                                                            at com.mysampleapp.RegisterUser.getPath(RegisterUser.java:346)
                                                                            at com.mysampleapp.RegisterUser.onActivityResult(RegisterUser.java:199)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can assign the value of `outputFileUri` inside the `onActivityResult` because the assignation is not necessary in `openImageIntent()`.

**Pass:**

```
final String fname = UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png";
final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
```

**Before:**

```
uri = outputFileUri;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: It is initialized in the very beginning, it is a global variable. In onActivity it is simply a null

Comment: I mean the assignation, instead do it in `openImageIntent()`, do it in `OnActivityResult`. I'm gonna update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `outputFileUri` is a field on your activity/fragment where this code lives. If so, you need to ensure that you are including this in your `onSaveInstanceState()` `Bundle` and restore it in `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Your process can be terminated while the camera app is in the foreground, so this `Uri` needs to be part of the state that is being restored.

Comment: outputFileUri at point of ActivityResult is equal to null but I don't understand why

Comment: @JanMichniewicz: Most likely, it is `null` because your process was terminated, so `outputFileUri` is `null`, because you are not holding to that `Uri` in your saved instance state `Bundle`. Also, delete `getPath()` and [use the `Uri` properly](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html).

Comment: How can I access savedInstanceState from within function not in "onCreate"?

Comment: @JanMichniewicz: You don't. `outputFileUri` is a field, AFAICT. You populate this field from the saved instance state `Bundle`, in `onCreate()`, if there is a `Bundle` to work with. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider